# Drupal create related node on node view

Tags: drupal

So if I have 2 custom content types book and review, I'd like a user(when viewing a specific book) to be able to create/attach a review to the book.

I've tried a few options.

1) Created a "create review" formblock and using panels made a custom node view panel for review, but I couldn't get the relationship to work.

2) I also tried overriding comments on the book type with the node type review, the problem with this is I'd like users to be also be able to comment on the book and I couldn't see the ability to add multiple comment types.

This seems pretty easy to do on node edit with node reference extension so I'm hoping this isn't a big ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [nodereference](http://drupal.org/project/cck) and [nodereference_url](http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url) modules.

You can simply create a nodereference field in your review content type, and configure it with nodereference_url widget.

Answer (score 0):

You partially answered your own question.  With the nodereference module in D6 (or just references in D7), you can create a link in the same place 'add a comment' appears (the .links div) which says "add a review".  This link is because "reviews" has a field called something like "book reference" which is a noderef field.  This review will automatically fill in the field with the book where the user clicked the link and, depending on how you set the field up, send you back to the referenced node (book) or the new review.

Comment: Thanks for the response, where exactly do I create the link that will appear next to 'add a comment'?

Comment: Set the widget type to "Reference from URL".  This will give you several useful fields relevant to this, including what you want the text to read ("add a new review") and the behavior once that new node is created.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an interesting screencast there that show how to use Views Attach and Node Reference URL to do what you want :

http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode37